# Коммуникативные стратегии и тактики

Tags: общие-вопросы

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как определять, где началась и где закончилась та или иная тактика в речи? Есть какая то определённая лексика у каждой тактики? Или каждый определяет именно так, как чувствует? 
Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

В каждой речевой ситуации человек ставит перед собой конкретные цели и использует для этого различные тактики, или речевые приемы. Например, продавец общается с потенциальным  покупателем.  Продавец заинтересован в продаже своего товара, а покупатель – в получении о предмете объективных сведений. В процессе общения каждый предлагает свою речевую тактику, которая соответствует  одному из стилей речи:   деловому, научному, нейтральному, публицистическому, разговорному.

Вначале стоит придерживаться нейтральной лексики, когда вы приводите примеры,  сообщаете  интересную информацию или ссылаетесь на авторитеты.  Для разнообразия можно использовать научный стиль, поразив собеседника знанием технической терминологии.  Но когда контакт уже  установлен, желательно  сделать речь более  эмоциональной, и даже отчасти перейти к к неформальному общению . Рассказанные к месту забавные истории, информация  о собственном опыте при решении подобных задач – все это   разговорный стиль.

Таким образом,  речевые задачи и приемы меняются в процессе общения, при этом  для каждого варианта  подбирается соответствующая  лексика.